# How can I display all tags from all users for a model instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, acts-as-taggable-on

I want to get all the tags from all the users in my app for a brand whose ID is 37. The following works but only gets the tags from one of the 2 users currently in the app:

```
<%= BrandUser.last.brand.tags.join(", ") %>
```

The following is my attempt but doesn't work:

```
<%= BrandUser.where(:brand_id => 37).each {|brand| p brand.tags} %>
```

- Brand has_many tags, has_many brand_users and has_many users through brand_users
- User has_many :brand_users and has_many :brands, :through => :brand_users
- BrandUser belongs_to :brand and belongs_to :user

Below is my schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20110824083919) do

  create_table "brand_users", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "brand_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "brands", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "user_id"
  end

  create_table "taggings", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "tag_id"
    t.integer  "taggable_id"
    t.string   "taggable_type"
    t.integer  "tagger_id"
    t.string   "tagger_type"
    t.string   "context"
    t.datetime "created_at"
  end

  add_index "taggings", ["tag_id"], :name => "index_taggings_on_tag_id"
  add_index "taggings", ["taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context"], :name => "index_taggings_on_taggable_id_and_taggable_type_and_context"

  create_table "tags", :force => true do |t|
    t.string "name"
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

**Solution**:

As per the answer below, running the following in the console gave me the tags I was looking for:

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging.where(:taggable_id => 37, :taggable_type => 'Brand', :tagger_type => 'User').includes(:tag)
```

However running the following also works:

```
Brand.find(37).all_tags_on(:tags)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select the tagging where the `taggable_id` is the `brand_id`, the `taggable_type` is `Brand`, the `tagger_type` is `User`, and include `tag`.

```
Tagging.where(:taggable_id => 37, :taggable_type => 'Brand', :tagger_type => 'User').include(:tag)
```

To do the same but only for users that are associated with the brand, and a :tagger_id field:

```
Tagging.where(:taggable_id => 37, :taggable_type => 'Brand', :tagger_type => 'User', :tagger_id => User.where('brands.id' => 37).joins(:brands).select('users.id')).include(:tag)
```

Comment: That won't work because I don't have a Tagging model. Only a Brand, User and BrandUser models

Comment: If you are using acts_as_taggable_on_steroids you do have a tagging model.  You didn't define it, but it is there.

Comment: You have a tagging model, pop open the console and check: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/tagging.rb

Comment: Take a look at the implementation of the acts_as_taggable_on method at the bottom of https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/acts_as_taggable_on.rb.  The class name is ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging

Comment: You don't implement it in the app, it's already there, try ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging.new